# Using Kony for cross-platform development

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, temenos-quantum

Been using Kony for a month now for cross-platform development. I'm not really a big fan of it but I would like to get your honest take on it. While I fully admit my lack of knowledge of it I find it tends to complicate development more often than not.

What is your take on Kony? Any suggestions for alternatives?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can consider developing app in kony if you have the following considerations:

1. Develop an app in a very short time frame
2. Develop the same app for multi-os, multi-channel support (Andorid, IOS - Mobile native, SPA, Tablet..)
3. No much complexities (Otherwise you need to go for FFI components)
4. Need a middle ware support

These are all just my personal views. You can google for more information to take any decisions.

Comment: Thank you. We have just finished the project and we came up with one conclusion, this is the first and last time we will use the bloody framework.

Comment: Seems it is ramping up now. With latest release 7.3, we are getting additional features. What is the version used in the project?